# Easy way to Convert from List<IEnumerable<object>> to List<object> C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert from `List<IEnumerable<object>>` to `List<object>` in C#

currently I am achieving this by looping 2 times like below.

```
// distributerFreezerList is List<IEnumerable<FreezerTagViewModel>> 
List<FreezerTagViewModel> taglist = new List<FreezerTagViewModel>();
foreach (var one in distributerFreezerList)
{
    foreach (var two in one)
    {
        FreezerTagViewModel tag = new FreezerTagViewModel();
        tag = two;
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way?

Comment: What exactly are you achieving with this code? Also, why are you overwriting the result of the constructor call with an assignment?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman I was converting `List<IEnumerable<object>>` to `List<object>` by looping 2 times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `SelectMany` in Linq for this. It flattens the nested list.

```
distributerFreezerList.SelectMany(item => item).ToList()
```

The `SelectMany` returns a `IEnumerable<object>`, so added a `ToList` to make it a list.

Comment: Plus `.ToList()`

Comment: Thanks, I had to add  `.ToList()` to end, but it worked.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Thx!